# Kotlin: issue with NestedScrollView with RecyclerView loading all data at start

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a fragment that has multiple elements in it, some textViews, imageViews, a page ViewPager for ads and at the bottom I have a recyclerView.  I want them all to scroll as one so I places then in a nested scrollView.  I set the recyclerView height to wrap_content and set the recyclerView.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false.  Everything works fine with small dataset but when I have a large dataset for the recyclerView it takes a few second and freeze the UI.  I see that the whole dataset is being is being drawn at the start and its not behaving like a recyclerView that only draws elements on the screen.(I know why this happen, because the recyclerView is as tall as the dataset, so please don't tell me this.). I know that having a scrolling widget inside a scrolling widget is not best practice but its the only way I have got the correct behavior to work.  Is there a way to have a recyclerView in a nested scroll view that only loads the part of the recyclerView but still scrolls as one? Or is there a better way to structure this layout?

(Is it posible to have the

> binding.RecyclerView.adapter = RecyclerView_Adapter()

on a different/background thread? I don't think so because its doing UI operations)

(I have tried setting a specific height to the recycler view but it scrolls independently from the Nested scrollView )

XML

> ```
>  <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
>     android:id="@+id/inicio_swipe_container"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
>
>     <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
>         android:id="@+id/NestedScrollView"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
>         app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
>         app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
>         app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
>
>         <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="match_parent">
>
>             <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
>                 android:id="@+id/"
>                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
>                 android:minHeight="300dp"
>                 app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/"
>                 app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
>                 app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
>                 app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
>                 app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/">
>
>                 <TextView
>                     android:id="@+id/"
>                     android:layout_width="0dp"
>                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                     android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
>                     android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
>                     android:text=""
>                     android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
>                     android:textStyle="bold"
>                     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
>                     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
>                     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
>
>                 <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
>                     android:id="@+id/"
>                     android:layout_width="0dp"
>                     android:layout_height="0dp"
>                     android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
>                     android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
>                     android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
>                     android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
>                     android:minHeight="200dp"
>                     app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/"
>                     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
>                     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
>                     app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/" />
>
>                 <LinearLayout
>                     android:id="@+id/"
>                     android:layout_width="0dp"
>                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                     android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
>                     android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
>                     android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
>                     android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
>                     android:orientation="horizontal"
>                     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
>                     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
>                     app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
>                     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"></LinearLayout>
>
>                 <ProgressBar
>                     android:id="@+id/"
>                     style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
>                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
>                     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
>                     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
>                     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
>
>             </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
>
>             <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
>                 android:id="@+id/"
>                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:minHeight="200dp"
>                 app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
>                 app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
>                 app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
>                 app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
>                 app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ConstraintLayout_Inicio_Avisos">
>
>                 <TextView
>                     android:id="@+id/"
>                     android:layout_width="0dp"
>                     android:layout_height="1dp"
>                     android:background="#c6c2c2"
>                     android:text="TextView"
>                     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
>                     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
>                     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
>
>
>                 <ImageView
>                     android:id="@+id/"
>                     android:layout_width="0dp"
>                     android:layout_height="75dp"
>                     android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
>                     android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
>                     android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
>                     android:src="@drawable/centralimperdibles"
>                     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
>                     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
>                     app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/line1" />
>
>                 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
>                     android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
>                     android:layout_width="0dp"
>                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                     android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
>                     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
>                     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
>                     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
>                     app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/" />
>
>                 <ProgressBar
>                     android:id="@+id/"
>                     style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
>                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
>                     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
>                     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
>                     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
>
>             </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
>
>
>
>         </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
>     </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
>
> </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
> ```

fragment

> val Grid = GridLayoutManager(activity, 2, RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false)
> binding.RecyclerView.layoutManager = Grid
> binding.RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
> binding.RecyclerView.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
> binding.RecyclerView.adapter = RecyclerView_Adapter()

The ideal behavior is that as you scroll down the top widgets disappear until the recycler view is the whole screen height and then the recyclerView can scroll.

Thank you.

**EDIT**

Trying to pagina the recycler view but the update not working. If I reset the adapter(the section commented out) it works but its slow because it drawing 40 items.  Why is notifyItemRangeInserted not working?

```
binding.NestedScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener { v, scrollX, scrollY, oldScrollX, oldScrollY ->

        if (scrollY >= binding.ConstraintLayoutInicio.measuredHeight - v.measuredHeight - 1000) {
            if(bottomOfScroll == 0) {
                println("BOTTOM SCROLL")

                if (ProductosForListaParts.value!![0].Id != "0") {
                    val newcount = ProductosForListaParts.value!!.count() + 20
                    var productosListPartsToAdd: ArrayList<Producto> = ArrayList()
                    ProductosForLista.value?.forEachIndexed { i, producto ->
                        if (i >= newcount-20 && i < newcount) {
                            productosListPartsToAdd.add(producto)
                        }
                    }
                    ProductosForListaParts.value!!.addAll(productosListPartsToAdd)
                    
                    binding.RecyclerViewHotBuy.adapter?.notifyItemRangeInserted(newcount - 20, 20)
                    
                    //binding.RecyclerViewHotBuy.adapter = Inicio_Producto_Adapter(
                    //    ProductosForListaParts.value!!, OrganizationDollar.value!!, SubirAlCarritoProductos,
                    //    CarritoProductosArray, BajarDelCarritoProductos, event, eventPesables)
                }

            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: If loading a lot of data freezes the UI you should implement pagination in your recycler view and make sure that the call loading the data is not executed on the main thread. Can you post your whole fragment and adapter code?

Comment: @LucaPizzini I think pagination is the correct path forward.

Comment: @LucaPizzini I think pagination is the correct path forward.  I am loading the data asynchronous OkHttpClient() so thats not the issue. The issue is that when the recyclerView is in the nested scrollView it creates all the view at one, voiding the purpose of the recyclerView that only loaded the view on the page and recycles the view.  So I'm working on the pagination by loading data to a second var and using the setOnScrollChangeListener to see when its close to the bottom and then add more data to the var and I would like to update the recycler view.  notifyItemRangeInserted not working